# setting the cursor after an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am using a contenteditable element in my code in which text turns into emojis. for example, `abc :)` should turn into `abc` . But, after the image appears in the contenteditable, the cursor moves back to the beginning of the conteneditable and the whole code stops working after that.

Here's the code that I am using:

```js
var data = {
  "value": ":)",
  "image": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSaW1KOeceO85Y7KfUXGyLZm1LfTwjhQspKKXUl3D3a5Mo1uz-AhA"
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      //alert("space bar");
      var contenteditable = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]'),
        text = contenteditable.textContent;
      var word = getWord(text);
      console.log(word);
      console.log(data.value);
      if (word.includes(data.value)) {
        //alert("true");
        var img = "<img id='image' src='" + data.image + "' class='image' /> ";
        console.log(img);
        $("#text-box").html(function(_, html) {
          return html.replace(data.value, img);
        }); //[0].setSelectionRange($("#text-box").html().length, $("#text-box").html().length);

        var el = document.getElementById("image");
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(el.childNodes[2], 2);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

      }
    }

    function getWord(text) {
      var word = text.split(" ").pop();
      return word;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 1.4em;
  max-width: 1.4em;
}

[contenteditable] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id='text-box'>
</div>
```

Here's the link to my Codepen:
[Link](https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/gWoRoK?editors=1111)